# How do I control localSCroll target area despite browser position

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I am making a site that is one giant scrolling page. I am using local scroll to scroll to sections. The trouble I am having is:

If I have my browser open as tall as it can be and click the link that goes to the target area, the top and bottom margins are different than if I had my browser half as tall. I am trying to get it to scroll to the same place no matter what. I am trying to get it to land on the same spot and have the same top and bottom margin areas no matter what.

For example, here is where it scrolls to when the browsers is tall as it gets

[image]

and here it is when the browser is very short

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 1000, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
</script>

<a class="nav" href="#home">
    Home
</a>
<h2 class="subtitle" id="about"></h2>
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try this <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/Wqq6g/)**</kbd>

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="nav" href="div1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav" href="div2">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav" href="div3">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav" href="div4">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav" href="div5">Link 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>
<div id="div5"></div>


$(function(){
  $('.nav').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#'+$(this).attr('href')).offset().top + 'px' }, 1000, 'swing');
  });
});
```